# Understanding results of `predict_proba`

Tags: scikit-learn, deep-learning, classification, prediction, tensorflow-probability

I using a deep neural network for prediction(which could either be 1 or 0). The problem been solved is a classification problem. I am using `predict_proba` of `sklearn` to predict probabilities of my prediction. As per my knowledge, the output of `predict_proba` shall have 2 columns per row denoting probability of each class.
What I am expecting is something like this:

```
[0.99467199 0.00532801]
[0.00223842 0.99776158]
[0.99389073 0.00610927]
```

But I am getting:

```
[[6.92488432e-01]
 [5.56170940e-04]
 [7.24569559e-01]
 [9.99984384e-01]]
```

How can I interpret these results? Does these value corresponding to the probability of class been predicted?

Comment: Add relevant code snippet in your question

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar this is a research project and I cannot give the model code here. What else shall I add here to make the ques clearer?

Answer (score 0):

This is normal, when you only have two classes, giving just the proba of one of them is enough because the other one can be found by substracting the proba of the first class from 1.

Comment: So what does my output shows? Does it show probability of class 0(or 1) or that of class been finally predicted?